# Weight paint in rest pose while previewing another pose

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, pose-mode

For example while weight painting this:

[image]

It's hard to precisely paint the overlapping part. I can set the armature to the rest pose and then paint, but this way I don't know how it looks when the bones are bent.

Is it possible to paint in the rest pose, while previewing the painted result in another pose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could link-duplicate both the object and the armature, reset the pose of the linked-duplicated armature, and weight paint the linked-duplicated object, you'll see the result on the original posed object.